# Dynamic CSS classes for printing

Tags: css, printing

**Usecase:** Clicking on a link opens an overlay with some content in it. There are many such links on the page, each of which has a corresponding content that loads inside the overlay. User should be able to print only the particular content.

**Approach:** On clicking the link, I am setting a class called "printer" to the body. Inside print.css, I am hiding all the page content EXCEPT what I see inside the overlay. On closing the overlay, I am removing the class from the body.

**Issue:** Everything seems to be working fine on FF and IE. On Chrome the print dialog hangs, whereas on Safari, I see a blank page.

Any help would be appreciated to understand what I might be doing wrong OR if any other approach exists.

Comment: Code please. Can't do much without it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use media type to apply a stylesheet that is used only for print.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="yourPrint.css"/>
```

or use @import within your current stylesheet

```
@media print {
  /* style sheet for print goes here */
}
```

for more info regarding this, check out w3.org http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html

and for a less technical albeit less reliable source, http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_mediatypes.asp

Comment: This is not dynamic. Sorry for being late to the party. :|

Answer (score 0):

Use Print CSS

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="print.css" />
```

Comment: Sorry, it is not so well researched question, an I noticed it just after! It's still true, though.

Comment: @loa_in_ Agreed. I know a dynamic solution that I have implemented, but it is not worth adding it here now.

Comment: Does it involve adding `style` tag to `head` with `media="print"` dynamically? I would love to see it, because I need to use JS to configure font size before printing, for print only. And I can't create a class for each possible font size :|

Comment: And there seems to be no truly cross-browser solution, client-side only.

Comment: It is a basic one, which is supported by all the browsers. Why not?

Comment: IE 8 tends to throw unknown errors, AFAIK because of hard limit on the number of style sheets in the document. I have no idea what my clients use. This problem is so niche. Thanks anyway, IE<9 is now officialy not on my supported list.